# ChartJS Bar chart painting second bar to the right

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I have a barchart using the latest version of charts.js. Now I need to show the bars and at the right, a bar that actually has nothing to do with the rest. (the first bars are thre monthly values, the last bar is the forecast for this month)

See here to better understand what I mean. https://jsbin.com/diqetaxeqi/edit?js,output

The forecast bar has it's own y axis on the right. I've struggled setting the bar to the right and have solved this by creating a new dataset filling the values with 0 to make sure it is the last bar that is drawn. The problem with this is that the labels are not centered anymore as the bars with 0 value is still painted.

How can I solve this better?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires 2 different datasets ? Or can they be all 4 like:

```
data: [18739460, 33056135, 36562034, 3234234] ?
```

Comment: They can all be the same, but I only want to draw the forecast bar as the last bar. Actually it should just be drawn once. you know, showing a forecast as bar to every month doesn't make sense as the forcast is for this month, not for the past.

Comment: Hey @Antonio. Thanks, but I don't want the forecast to be on the same yAxis than the rest. This would cause a lot of problems if for instance the last months had values like 1000 and 1500 but the forecast it like 30.000. You would not be able to see the lower values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. stacking the bars does the trick.

do

```
stacking:true
```

at xAxis